# Complete list of all followed/committed sites on area51

Tags: feature-request, area-51

Is there a way to see a list of all the sites I've followed or committed to (generally, I'd call that "shown interest")?  Currently, the list of proposals on my profile page only lists proposals I've committed to that haven't launched and proposals I've followed that haven't  entered beta.

Currently, it appears I have to go through the beta and launched lists and look for the "followed" or "committed" marker.  Quite inconvenient.

What I would want is a list like http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/28131/jurgen-a-erhard but including all those that have launched (the first list) or are in/past beta (the third list).  I mean, *in one place*.  The info is there, sure, but in separate places.

Comment: Clarified (I hope).  Example for the "committed and launched, doesn't show" is dba.SE.  Example for "followed and entered beta, doesn't show" is music.SE.

Comment: (And for some reason, all comments disappeared here... even my own, which I certainly didn't delete)

Comment: Am I correct that what you want is [this list](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/28131?tab=accounts) + [this list](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/28131/jurgen-a-erhard) - any sites you only got interested in post-launch? And if yes, why? It's easier to figure out what to do if you can explain how it would be useful (at first glance, I can't figure out a purpose for this info, but it's clear you want it).

Comment: @Dori: to paraphrase my question: currently, when I follow a proposal and this proposal enters beta, it disappears from my *area51* profile (as do proposals that I committed to that get launched).  All I want is a list of proposals I followed and/or committed to *in one place*.  As I say, at this time I have to hunt for this info (answering the question: "has one of my followed proposals entered beta", for example) in two places, however you look at it.  The info is there, sure... but not *in one place*

Comment: I understand the *what*; what I don't get is the *why*. If I understood what it is you'd want to do with the info, it might turn out that there's an existing method or a workaround.